# Solo me sale código HTML cuando corro mi página web desarrollada en Python con reflex

Tags: python

he hecho una pequeña página web, pero después de la actualización de reflex he tenido muchos problemas con las librerías usadas y a pesar de solucionar ese error compila con `reflex run` pero en la página que me muestra solo hay código.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Podrías agregar que es lo que has intentado hasta el momento para que se pueda solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Dado que es una página web, diría que es correcto que _salga_ código HTML. ¿Qué es lo que le falta o qué es lo incorrecto con esto?